# Why are there 3 cables going into 2 switch electrical box

Tags: electrical, junction-box

Three main cables going into this 2 switch junction box. Going to move the switches up 6” and don’t understand why there are 3 main cables going to this box.
There is an outlet below and to the left of this box. Could it be for that?
[image]

Comment: Hard to see how the wires are connected or pass though in the box.  Good possibility that one cable is power from the panel, and either powers the switches or passes right though to the outlet.

Comment: one for power and one for each light perhaps?

Comment: Can you post a photo clearly showing the back of the box please?

Comment: Is there a cable coming out of the *bottom* of the box?

Comment: With the power off, remove the 4 screws holding the switches to the box, then pull the switches out. Do _NOT_ remove any wires from the switches. Once you have them out of the box, the answer will likely become very obvious to you, but if you're still not sure, [edit] your question with some pics of the wiring and someone will clarify for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly a power-in cable feeding both switches and then a cable to the fixtures controlled by the 2 switches. With the power off, pull out the switches and take a couple of pics of the wiring. Then we can be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Sort of.

One set went to one switch on the right. The other 2 cables had their white wires twisted together for grounding and taped together and both black to the 2nd switch.

I don’t know why, but at least I do know what. I had to move the box and switches up a few inches so I made sure I kept the wiring the same.